# Javascript backgroundColor works on some computers, not on others?

Tags: javascript, background-color

This part of javascript code works on my home computer, but doesn't at work. Also, my colleague tested it and it doesn't work on her home computer?!

```js
function klikNaX(x, y, z) {
  var u = document.getElementById(z);
  var u2;
  u2 = u.style.backgroundColor;
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = (z + " " + u2);
}
```

The problem seems to be with this part

```html
u.style.backgroundColor;
```

Comment: Please post your HTML

Comment: What browsers are they using?

Comment: Ok, thank you all, it was an error made by me in php :)
I obviously used different example data at home and at work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a problem of `style.backgroundColor`, instead please check if 'u' is a valid node and not undefined.
And try setting a color to `u.style.backgroundColor = 'green'`